# Blur only text-fields and select-fields

Tags: jquery, html, input

I want the `.blur()` to only trigger on text-fields(`input type="text"`) and select-fields(`input type="select"`).

How can I accomplish this?

I have checkboxes in my field-list, but don't want the `.blur()` to trigger when the value in the checkboxes is changed.

```
$('#tele :input').blur(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.currentTarget).val() == "") {
        service_info = $(e.currentTarget).val(); //Innehåller värdet i input-fälten
        id = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id');
        service = "tele";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'summary.php',
            data: {service_info: service_info, id: id, service: service},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) { $('#table_right #services_tele').html(data); },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(thrownError); }  
        });     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#tele input[type="text"], #tele select').blur()
```

Answer (score 0):

This selector should do:

```
$("input[type='text'], select").blur()
```

BTW, there is no `input[type='select']`. It should be just `select`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$('input[type="text"], select').blur(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.currentTarget).val() == "") {
        service_info = $(e.currentTarget).val(); //Innehåller värdet i input-fälten
        id = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id');
        service = "tele";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'summary.php',
            data: {service_info: service_info, id: id, service: service},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) { $('#table_right #services_tele').html(data); },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(thrownError); }  
        });     
    }
});
```